# Does openssl refuse self signed certificates without basic constraints?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have two extremely similar self signed certificates, generated via two different methods.

To test them I have:

1. Added an entry in my hosts file for local.mydomain.com
2. Set up an nginx server to listen on that domain on port 443 with the certificate under test plus associated private key (I then switch the cert and restart nginx to compare)
3. Connected to nginx with `openssl s_client -connect local.mydomain.com -CAfile /path/to/the/ca/cert.pem`

One certificate fails:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = local.mydomain.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = local.mydomain.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=local.mydomain.com
   i:/CN=local.mydomain.com
---
```

One certificate succeeds:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = local.mydomain.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN = local.mydomain.com
   i:/CN = local.mydomain.com
---
```

I compare the details of the certificates with `openssl x509 -in /path/to/the/ca/cert.pem -text -noout`

The failing cert:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            47:dc:02:c7:11:fc:8e:96:45:22:aa:6b:23:79:32:ca
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=local.mydomain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 18 11:55:31 2016 GMT
            Not After : Nov 18 12:15:31 2017 GMT
        Subject: CN=local.mydomain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    <stuff>
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:local.mydomain.com
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                6D:4F:AF:E4:60:23:72:E5:83:27:91:7D:1D:5F:E9:7C:D9:B6:00:2A
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         <stuff>
```

The working cert:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            9b:6b:3d:a3:b9:a3:a4:b4
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=local.mydomain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 19 13:27:30 2016 GMT
            Not After : Nov 19 13:27:30 2017 GMT
        Subject: CN=local.mydomain.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    <stuff>
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                03:E7:DA:AA:2E:CC:23:ED:C5:07:3D:E1:33:86:F5:22:D4:76:EB:CB
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:03:E7:DA:AA:2E:CC:23:ED:C5:07:3D:E1:33:86:F5:22:D4:76:EB:CB

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         57<stuff>
```

Looking at this the most obvious difference is that the working cert has `CA:TRUE` under `X509v3 Basic Constraints`. However, from reading around the web I was under the impression that self signed certs weren't meant to be CAs, in particular this says they normally won't be:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44340/basic-self-signed-certificate-questions

The answer there says that being self-signed there is no CA involved. But maybe openssl requires self signed certs to have that set anyway?

Comment: A better site for asking this question might be security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: OK I'll try there too, thanks!

Comment: There are two types of certificates. First are CA certificates. CA certificates can issue other certificates. They are signaled with `Basic Constraint CA=Yes`. The second is an end-entity certificate. End-entity certificates are server and client certificates. They are the leaf certificates. A *Self-Signed* certificate is a certificate where *Issuer=Subject*, *Authority Key Identifier=Subject Public Key Identifier*, etc. That's what it means to be self-signed. Both an end-entity or CA certificate can be self signed. When its a CA, it usually refers to as a *Root CA*.

Comment: @jww it's a web server, which implies it's an end-entity certificate. So does that mean openssl is incorrect to refuse it when it's missing `Basic Constraint CA=Yes`?

Comment: @unichiro - It sounds wrong to me. If its an end-entity certificate, then CA=false should be set. Key Usage and Extended Key Usage could factor into it. We probably need to check the RFCs to see what is supposed to be specified, and what is supposed to happen. Also, the first/failing certificate looks like the *Distinguished Name* is not quite right. The DN's are used in [RFC 4158 for Path Building](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4158.txt). You might be seeing an artifact of a malformed DN. There was also a bug in the way OpenSSL used DNs that may be affecting things. It was fixed a while ago.

Comment: Just to be sure I've changed the DN to be the same in the openssl-generated cert (made everything but CN empty), and it still works

Comment: @junichiro - Check out [RFC 5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt). RFC 5280 is PKIX or the Internet's PKI. That's where most of the rules are for issuing certificates. The remainder can usually be found in [RFC 4158](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4158.txt).

Comment: x-post: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/143061/2328

Answer (score 1):

From my own experiments I can confirm what you see. My explanation of the behavior is that a self signed certificate is still a certificate which is signed by the issuer, even if the issuer's certificate is the certificate itself. But only CA certificates can be used to sign certificates, i.e. that's exactly the constraint CA:true allows. This means that a self-signed certificate needs also to be a CA certificate with the constraint CA:true.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9) says:

> The CA boolean indicates whether the certified public key may be used
> to verify certificate signatures.

So, if your certificate does not have `CA:TRUE` flag, this certificate may not be used to verify the signature on any certificate, including itself. OpenSSL correctly follows the RFC.

It is incorrect to think that a certificate belongs to one of two types, either "CA certificate" or "end-entity certificate". A certificate with `CA:TRUE` can be used for authenticating the entity. This is exactly what you do when you authenticate with a self-signed certificate. It can also be a certificate with `CA:TRUE`, signed by someone else.